Expose ports on a GithHub Docker Action
Problem
I've been trying to setup a SurrealDB container within my test job in GitHub Actions. The step I am currently struggling with is that I can't find a way to expose the ports on my surreal-db custom docker action. Previously, I have also tried using a service container (my understanding is that the service container is usually used for that purpose).
Attempts to solve it

Running it as a service container:

  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      SURREAL_USER: ${{ secrets.SURREAL_USER }}
      SURREAL_PASS: ${{ secrets.SURREAL_PASS }}
      SURREAL_PORT: ${{ vars.SURREAL_PORT }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      ...

    services:
      db:
        image: surrealdb/surrealdb:latest
        # Problem here is that I can't use the entrypoint property to launch the server
        ports:
          - ${{ vars.SURREAL_PORT }:8000


Creating a custom GitHub action to run it

...
inputs:
  surreal-user:
    description: "Username for the account"
    required: false
    default: "root"
  surreal-pass:
    description: "Password for the account"
    required: false
    default: "root"
  surreal-port:
    description: "Port to expose on the host machine"
    required: false
    default: "8000"

runs:
  using: "docker"
  image: docker://surrealdb/surrealdb:latest
  entrypoint: "entrypoint.sh"
  args:
    - ${{ inputs.surreal-user }}
    - ${{ inputs.surreal-pass }}
    - ${{ inputs.surreal-port }}
  # ... and here I can't use the ports property

I am thinking that there must be a way to expose the ports somehow. Anyone know how? Or do you have an alternative way of working around that problem?

Can you try something like the following and let me know if that worked? Also use the official surrealdb/setup-surreal@v1 action.
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Test
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Start SurrealDB
      uses: surrealdb/setup-surreal@v1
      with:
        surrealdb_version: latest
        surrealdb_port: 8000
        surrealdb_username: root
        surrealdb_password: root
        surrealdb_auth: false
        surrealdb_strict: false
        surrealdb_log: info


Yes, it did! Thanks for pointing this out to me!

Instead of creating a custom Docker action or using a service container, you can use the official surrealdb/setup-surreal@v1 action. This action is specifically designed to set up and run SurrealDB in GitHub Actions.
You can follow this step by step guide to Use SurrealDB in GitHub actions.
